# Is there a non-right-orderable torsion-free quotient group of the braid group on 3 strands?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, ordered-groups

The braid group on 3 strands has the presentation $\langle x,y \;|\; xyx=yxy\rangle$. A group $G$ is called right-orderable if there is a total order $<$ on the set $G$ such that if $a<b$ then $ac<bc$ for all $c\in G$.
It is known that braid groups are right-orderable.

Is there a non-right-orderable torsion-free quotient group of the braid group on 3 strands?

Comment: What do you mean by a factor?

Comment: @HJRW: factor means quotient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there are many such examples. The braid group is isomorphic to the fundamental group of the trefoil knot complement. The trefoil knot $T$ admits many Dehn fillings, parameterized by $r\in \mathbb{Q} \cup \{\infty\}$. If $|r|\geq 1$, then the Dehn filling $S^3_r(T)$ is an L-space. Moreover, it is usually Seifert-fibered and has torsion-free fundamental group. By Theorem 4 of [Boyer-Gordon-Watson](http://www.cirget.uqam.ca/boyer/Publications/bgw.pdf), these Dehn fillings do not have orderable fundamental group (the notion of L-space is actually not relevant to the answer to this question, it just gave the quickest way to cite the literature).

Comment: What is $\hat{\mathbb{Q}}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{QP}^1$ - I changed the notation, since this is probably only used by 3-manifold topologists.

Comment: @IanAgol: Is it known a group presentation (not necessarily finite) for $\pi_1(S_r^3(T))$ for some $r$ with $|r|\geq 1$?

Comment: @IanAgol: I mean for those $r$ such that $\pi_1(S_r^3(T))$ is not right orderable and is torsion-free.

Comment: Yes, it is easy to obtain such representations. One adds a relation of the form m^a*l^b, where r=a/b and m is the longitude, l the meridian.

Comment: @IanAgol: Sorry to ask further. You mean that to define $\pi_1(S_r^3(T))$ one needs only 2 relations (one of Braid group $B_3$ i.e. $xyx=yxy$ and another one, that you explain above) or the relation you gave is a series of relations. I can ask it as a new question.

Comment: Yes, those two relations (I didn't compute m and l, but this should be easy).

Comment: @IanAgol: For any torsion-free non-left-orderable factor $B_3/N$ of $B_3$, we know that $N$ must be a free subgroup of $B_3$ such that $N\cap Z(B_3)=1$. It is a necessary  condition. So it does not seem (or at least surprising) one can define a torsion-free non-left-orderable factor of $B_3$ with finitely many relations.

Comment: I don't understand your logic - why can't there be finitely many relators?

Comment: I do not say it must be "finitely presented" only I am surprised. Don't mind! Sorry.

Comment: My last comment: So we have in hand a torsion-free non-left orderable group defining by two generators and two relations. So the group may have Unique Product property?! If not, we have also a surprising group.