# Relations between $\Omega$-groups, locally indicable groups, and right-orderable groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, geometric-group-theory, ordered-groups

We know that the class of right-orderable groups $\mathit{RO}$, is contained in the class of $\Omega$-groups (read it from "*A note on group rings of certain torsion-free groups*" by Burns-Hale).

A group $G$ is a right-orderable group if there exists a total order $\leq$ on $G$ s.t. if $ a \leq b$ $\implies$ $ag \leq bg$   $\forall g \in G$

A group $G$ is an $\Omega$-group if for every ordered pair of nonempty finite subsets $A$, $B$ of $G$ 
there is at least one pair $(a,b)$ $\in$ $A \times B$ s.t. $ab\neq a'b'$ for any other ordered pair $(a',b') \in A \times B$.

A group is locally indicable if every nontrivial finitely generated subgroup admits $\mathbb{Z}$ as quotient group.

> Are all locally indicable groups $\Omega$-groups? and is there any proof relating the containment of the class of locally indicable groups in the class of RO-groups? (either up to some point or showing that they aren't contained?) Also what about containment of the class of $\Omega$-groups in $\mathit{RO}$?

Comment: If I recall correctly  locally idicable groups are right orderable.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207996/u-p-unique-product-group-which-is-not-right-ordered-ro/208001 seems to answer your second question.